# Binary Subtraction VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, binary, subtraction

I would like to ask some help about Binary Subtraction in Visual Basic 2010 .My code works well, thanks to @video.baba

```
Dim BinaryResult As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text, 2) + Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text, 2)
Textbox3.Text = BinaryResult.ToString
```

eventually, the problem is this. If the 1st input is lower from the 2nd input that gives me a result of negative but the answer is so far away

Example :

```
0000 - 1111 = 11111111111111111111111111111001
```

MUST BE

```
0000 - 1111 = -01111
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `-01111` isn't valid binary. May I ask why you expect this output? What currently get is correct, see: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BGsDry

Comment: What's happening is when your unsigned int "goes negative" it gets promoted to a signed int, which uses the left most bit to represent negative v. positive (1 = neg, 0 = pos). [If your still confused, this should explain it](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/binary-to-decimal.html?x=11111111111111111111111111111001)

Comment: @VisualVincent it must be 0000 - 1111 = -01111 right not 11111111111111111111111111111001 .Asking for a help if whats the best code rather for binary subtraction in vbnet

Comment: Did you check my link? What you get _**is**_ right. `-01111` is not a valid binary number since `-` doesn't exist in binary. Like doom87er explained, the left most bit (the first from the left) indicates whether the number is positive or negative. That long string is how your computer represents a negative number, ergo it's what's truly right.

Comment: okay then thanks now i understand it :) btw any other code for binary subtraction please? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want the output to be `-01111` (or `-1111`, since the leading zero is omitted) you have to make the number positive and then prepend the binary string with the minus sign.

Then, when converting it back you have to remove the sign and make the resulting number negative again.

Converting to binary:

```
Dim BinaryResult As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text, 2) - Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text, 2)

If BinaryResult < 0 Then
    TextBox3.Text = "-" & Convert.ToString(-BinaryResult, 2)
Else
    TextBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(BinaryResult, 2)
End If
```

Converting from binary:

```
Dim BinaryResult As Integer

If TextBox3.Text.StartsWith("-") Then
    BinaryResult = -Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text.TrimStart("-"c), 2)
Else
    BinaryResult = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text, 2)
End If
```

**Reusable version:**

```
Private Function BinarySubtract(ByVal a As String, ByVal b As String) As String
    Dim BinaryResult As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(a, 2) - Convert.ToInt32(b, 2)
    If BinaryResult < 0 Then
        Return "-" & Convert.ToString(-BinaryResult, 2)
    Else
        Return Convert.ToString(BinaryResult, 2)
    End If
End Function

Private Function FromBinary(ByVal s As String) As Integer
    If s.StartsWith("-") Then
        Return -Convert.ToInt32(s.TrimStart("-"c), 2)
    Else
        Return Convert.ToInt32(s, 2)
    End If
End Function
```

**Online test:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/PoQZA6